# Vite build compiled files based on directories

Tags: laravel, vite, laravel-vite

this is something that I used to do in gulp and webpack but I'm not able to achieve this on vite.

I have different themes in different folders like

```
resources/
    themes/
         theme1/
              js/
              css/
         theme2/
              js/
              css/
```

I'm trying to build files in their separate folders based on theme name like this should be the output

```
public/
     build/
         theme1/
         theme2/
```

I've tried to follow a lot of forums but couldn't get the code to work. I also tried using vitemulti builder but there must be something I'm missing. This is my code

```
export default defineConfig({
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            'resources/themes/default/sass/app.scss': '/resources/themes/default/css/app.css',
        },
    },
    plugins: [
        vue(),
        laravel({
            input: [
                'resources/themes/theme1/sass/app.scss',
                'resources/themes/theme1/js/app.js',
                'resources/themes/theme2/sass/app.scss',
                'resources/themes/theme2/js/app.js',
            ],
            refresh: true,
        }),

        /*viteMultiBundler({
            file_versioning: true,
            js: [
                {
                    filename: "theme1",
                    entryPoints: ['resources/themes/theme1/js/app.js'],
                },
                {
                    filename: "theme2",
                    entryPoints: ['resources/themes/theme2/js/app.js'],
                }
            ],
            sass: [
                {
                    filename: "theme1",
                    entryPoints: ['resources/themes/theme1/sass/app.scss'],
                },
                {
                    filename: "theme2",
                    entryPoints: ['resources/themes/theme2/sass/app.scss'],
                }
            ]
        }),*/
    ],
});

Can anyone  help me achieve the desired output?
```

Answer (score 0):

In Vite, you can use the `build.rollupOptions` configuration to specify multiple input files and their output paths.

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue2'

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        vue(),
        laravel({
            refresh: true,
        }),
    ],
    build: {
        rollupOptions: {
            input: {
                'theme1/app': 'resources/themes/theme1/js/app.js',
                'theme2/app': 'resources/themes/theme2/js/app.js',
            },
        },
    },
    css: {
        preprocessorOptions: {
            scss: {
                additionalData: `@import "resources/themes/theme1/sass/app.scss"; @import "resources/themes/theme2/sass/app.scss";`,
            },
        },
    },
    server: {
        port: 3500
    },
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            vue: 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js'
        }
    }
})
```

In this configuration, the `build.rollupOptions.input` option is used to specify the input files and their output paths. The keys of the `input` object are the output paths relative to the `outDir` (which defaults to `dist`), and the values are the corresponding input file paths.